# Can we add SVG icon in Picker.Item?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-picker-select

I am trying to add SVG icons in <Picker.Item /> using **react-native-picker/picker** library but it doesn't show.

Here I am putting a piece of code:

```
(language, index) => {
  return(
    <Picker.Item
      label={ <EnglishFlag height={25} width={25} /> + language.name}
      value={language.value}
      key={index}
     />
  )
});
```

I want to mention that I want to use only svg icon not emoji. Is there any way to do in this form?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag emoji by copy from some website and paste it in string like below,
`<Picker.Item label="  France" value="fr" />`